# wp_list _table You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page error

Tags: errors

I'm trying to develop a plugin which uses custom post and custom database table with class that extends the wp_list_table to show the data from a database table. But everytime I try to do something with the record it just gives me an error that I don't have sufficient permissions. I'm trying to do the rollover edit and delete and bulk action delete and also the search box. But when I click on the button it always gives me this error and I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
I just needed to change the form method from get to post and I don't have an error that I don't have sufficient permissions anymore.